# HTML form - POST or GET depending on button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Let there be a search form with quite many of the input fields. The user may either click:

- [Search] and GET the list of the results,
- [Save search criteria] for future use and POST the form content to be stored on server (I'm not interested in storing locally in cookies or so).

How do I achieve that? I've only found solutions to make two types of POST request on two separate buttons.

Maybe a JavaScript onclick function to set `<form method="??">` right before its submitted? Would that work?

Comment: So you already got your concept. Follow it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTML5, the `<input>` element got [some new attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp)

```
<input type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="save.php" value="Save" />
<input type="submit" formmethod="get" formaction="search.php" value="Search" />
```

The same attributes are [valid for `<button>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> Yes you can change form method before submit form using jquery

```
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    <button onclick="changeMethod()">submit</button>
</form>
```

Function changeMethod in jquery

```
function changeMethod(){
    $("#myForm").attr("method", "get");
}
```

Comment: Why give your example with jquery?