# Why form is getting posted to wrong URL even after setting action URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, laravel

**UPDATE:** See, The form is getting submitted but at the wrong URL! If you are here to teach how to set attributes according to user's action, please don't try to help because I know that sheet!

I am working on **Laravel** and I have **One form** with **Two submit buttons**. I want to submit form according to the button clicked by the user.

I already tried editing **Button** tag and did almost everything that is given on other answers but nothing seems to work!

Here is the Form code.

```
<form method="POST" class="form-material" id="form1">
     {{ csrf_field() }}
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail Address" required/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required/>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group actionButtons">
         <p data-action="form1Register" class="btn btn-md btn-info actionButton">Create Account</p>
         <p data-action="form1Login" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-info hidden-md-down actionButton">Login</p><br>
         <small>By Signing up, You agree to <a href="{{ url('tos') }}" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>.</small>
     </div>
</form>
```

And Yeah, here is the bit of Jquery I am trying to implement.

```
$(".actionButton").click(function() {
    if($(this).data('action') == 'form1Login'){
        $('#form1').attr('action','{{ action("SessionController@store") }}');
        $('#form1').submit();
    } else if($(this).data('action') == 'form1Register') {
        $('#form1').attr('action','{{ action("UserController@store") }}');
        $('#form1').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Oops! Something went really wrong!');
    }
});
```

I am not using `<button>` tags because it submits the form and there is no way to stop it I think. I already tried giving it a `type='button'` attribute but it is not working too! It still submits the freaking form!

Is there anything I am missing? Because I am using the same thing on one of the other systems but it is working fine there!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML form - POST or GET depending on button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987384/html-form-post-or-get-depending-on-button-clicked)

Comment: @tkausl, Please read the question again. It's not about freaking **GET** and **POST** methods! It's about two completely different action URLs and same method.

Comment: The answer does answer your question though.

Comment: @tkausl, Please don't comment or take action against any questions about reading it. How do you know it will work. Are you sure?

Comment: @tkausl, I know how to set attributes based on user's action! And when I alert the action URL, it is showing me the URL on which I want to POST the data! But then it is not submitting data to that URL! The page is getting reloaded!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".actionButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).data('action') == 'form1Login'){
        $('#form1').attr('action','{{ action("SessionController@store") }}');
        $('#form1').submit();
    } else if($(this).data('action') == 'form1Register') {
        $('#form1').attr('action','{{ action("UserController@store") }}');
        $('#form1').submit();
    } else {
        alert('Oops! Something went really wrong!');
    }
});
```

//you should prevent the default action of action button

Comment: Thanks for help brother but still, the form is not getting submitted to the `register` or `login` URLs. It is being redirected to itself, don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

Special Note for Laravel Users!

The form was getting submitted to the right URL. But as I was using the **laravel's Default validator**, It was redirecting me back to the URL from where the form was located.

So, If you are laravel user and want to submit a form to the different URL the make your own custom Validator so that you can redirect back to some different URL.

Thanks everyone for helping me solve the Issue!